# Calculate container height of pinboard style blog (based on absolute elements)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing a pinboard-style blog (like Pinterest) using the [tutorial by Ben Holland](http://benholland.me/javascript/2012/02/20/how-to-build-a-site-that-works-like-pinterest.html). Each pin has an absolute position and its location (top and left) is being calculated with jQuery script http://labs.benholland.me/pinterest/js/script-centered.js

Everything works perfectly ([see demo](http://labs.benholland.me/pinterest/demo-centered.php)), but the only thing that needs doing is adding footer. When I try to add footer (no matter how it is positioned:  relatively or absolutely), it shows up either on the top of the page (`position:relative`) or it floats somewhere in the middle of the page (`position:absolute;bottom:0`). Footer never shows up underneath the blog.

I tried many CSS solutions (clearfixes, floats, a variety of different position combinations), after all this I came to the conclusion that it is impossible without JS.

The problem can be solved by placing the pinboard in the **container**, giving the container `position:relative` and adding the correct height. After this, footer can be placed below the container. And this is where I'm stuck.

I'm a beginner at JavaScript, can somebody help me to to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you said,you may use a div to contain these absolute elements
The construct like:

```
<body onload="setupBlocks();">
    <header>header</header>
    <section id="container">
        <div class="block">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....</p>
        </div>
        ......
    </section>
    <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

and css code like:

```
header{height:30px;background-color:green;}
footer{height:20px;background-color:gray;}
section{position:relative;} //It's important,absolute element will calculate position depending on nearest parent which has sure position.
```

as to js code,Please look at array:block[],this array has the record of every column's height，you can print it in console.
so what you need to do is just set max value of block[] to section.
here I added two lines in function positionBlocks and a function to get max value

```
function positionBlocks() {
$('.block').each(function(i){
    var min = Array.min(blocks);
    var index = $.inArray(min, blocks);
    var leftPos = margin+(index*(colWidth+margin));
    $(this).css({
        'left':(leftPos+spaceLeft)+'px',
        'top':min+'px'
    });
    blocks[index] = min+$(this).outerHeight()+margin;
}); 
var max = Array.max(blocks);    //you need to write a function to get max value of block
$('section').height(max);       //set section(or div,as you wish)'s height
}

// Function to get the Min value in Array
Array.min = function(array) {
    return Math.min.apply(Math, array);
};

// Function to get the Max value in Array
Array.max = function(array) {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, array);
};
```

if you want to let your foot in the end if section's height too small,you need to calculate (scollheight-other's height)、compare with section's height and replace it in set seciton's height line.